# Xampp and Ampps don't reload files when changed

Tags: html, apache, xampp

When I change a file in the directory, the change is not reflected on the web page shown when I access it through localhost, but it is shown when I access it directly by the file path on my system. Why?

I am on a Windows machine. My files are stored at C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\connor.dev . When I directly reference a file, by going to a link like this in the browser, file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Ampps/www/connor.dev/index.php, the changes I made and saved in Sublime Text are shown. When I access it by going to localhost/connor.dev/, the changes are not shown. Even if I delete the file completely, it is still shown in localhost. This started happening recently on xampp, so I uninstalled it and used Ampps, and now the same thing is happening. If you need more info please ask.

Comment: There are many different possible reasons for this. You need to narrow down the problem and describe your environment.

Comment: lxg I am on a Windows machine. My files are stored at C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\connor.dev . When I directly reference a file, by going to a link like this in the browser, file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Ampps/www/connor.dev/index.php, the changes I made and saved in Sublime Text are shown. When I access it by going to localhost/connor.dev/, the changes are not shown. Even if I delete the file completely, it is still shown in localhost. This started happening recently on xampp, so I uninstalled it and used Ampps, and now the same thing is happening. If you need more info please ask.

Comment: Please add that information to your question. You can (and should) edit the post to contain as much useful information as possible.

Comment: Perhaps the server uses files from a different  folder. Or data is cached in the browser.

Comment: Do you have an `index.html` file as well along with `index.php` in that `connor.dev` directory? If so, you will be making your changes in the PHP file but when you go to `localhost/connor.dev/` it loads the html file by default. You can verify this by going to `localhost/connor.dev/index.html` and `localhost/connor.dev/index.php`

Comment: @kums I do not have any other index file.

Comment: And @Kwebble, how would I tell if the browser has a cached folder? And I've deleted the instance of this website everywhere else on the computer, so it's not possible that it uses another folder.

Comment: Use Ctrl-F5 in a browser to force it to skip the cache

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Press Ctrl-F5 to hard refresh the page (to not use Browser's cache).

If you still see the previous pages or changes, then Apache has mod_cache caching them, or PHP has its opcode cache settings set to not refresh changes for X amount of time.

Comment: Thanks, it works.  updated the php.ini by opcache.enable=0

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Bitnami and the way I fixed it was to go inside C:\Bitnami\wappstack-version-number\php\php.ini, you can make the following changes and then reset your server:

```
opcache.enable=0
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
```

My php was updating every 60 seconds before, so I decided to turn that to 0 and just disable caching.

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because of apache `mod_cache` caching the resources.

For quick fix. Just restart the Apache server.

In ubuntu i use this below command in terminal to restart the Apache server

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Now refresh the browser, then you will get the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

It comes out to be an issue with the cache thing, so in simple words all you have to do is to remove the cached data of the specific webpage.