# Loading JSON file not reflecting changes

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a JSON file I use to store dialogue for a game. However, the changes I make to this JSON file are sometimes not reflected in my game even after hard reloads (I've been doing ctrl+shift+r or shift+F5 for this). I have made sure the changes to the JSON file are saved.

I have `this.load.json('dialogue', 'assets/dialogue.json');` in preload(), and `this.dialogue = this.cache.json.get('dialogue');`  in create().

When I try copy+pasting the contents to a new different file (e.g. dialogue-2.json), and update my this.load.json() to reflect the new file name, the changes do get loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that phaser doesn't automatic start the loading files, except in the `preload` function.

If you want to load files in other *functions* you need to call the `start` method of the `LoadPlugin`. Here the link [to the official documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.LoaderPlugin.html#start__anchor).

The code should look something like this:

```
function create(){
    // some code here ... 
    this.load.json(/* key and file...*/);
    // start the loading of the enqueued files
    this.load.start();
    // some code here...
}
```

..., than the files should get loaded.

**Update *(copied form comments)*:**

to check *(and as a tempoary quickfix)* if your problem, is a caching issue from the Webserver or browser or ..., you can load the file with a *"dynamic" Url*.
Just a load the file with a questionmark and random number added to the url, so that each call to the json uses aunique Url.

**For Example like this:**
`this.load.json('dialogue', 'assets/dialogue.json?' + Math.random());`

If this solves the problem, there is a caching problem. It could be in the browser, or simply caused by serviceworker or on the webserver.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have some follow up questions. Initially, the this.load.json() was in the preload(). Shouldn't the start method get called automatically then? Also, I have tried adding load.json() and load.start() in create(), but it is giving me an error: ```phaser-arcade-physics.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'cut')```. I have also tried calling load.start() in preload() after load.json(), but the changes are stil not reflected.

Comment: @aki-02 Sorry I misunderstund. Yes, If all is loaded in `preload` it should work. well I thought you wanted to load the json, dynamicly again in the `create`/`update` function. But if you only changing the content of the file and than reloading the browser, _than the problem would have to_ do with the webserver/bundler that you are using. It might be caching the file (not sending the right caching header), or only not watching for changes of json files. What bundler / Webserver are you using?

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I am using XAMPP. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308810/xampp-and-ampps-dont-reload-files-when-changed, I have updated php.ini to have ```opcache.enable=0```, ```opcache.revalidate_freq=0```, restarted XAMPP, and hard reloaded several times but the changes are still not reflecting. Would you have any ideas on what else I could be missing?

Comment: @aki-02 Hmmm, tricky problem. As a fast workaround you could load the json like this `this.load.json('dialogue', 'assets/dialogue.json?' + Math.random())`, now it should work, ***if caching is the problem***. If it does work with this workaround, the problem is something else. *Info:* to add this `'?' + Math.random()` to the url, prevents the browser to cache the file, since each url is now unique.

Comment: Adding the ```'?' + Math.random()``` seems to have done the trick. Now, hard reloads are reflecting the changes made in the json files. Thank you!